# Existence of dominating measure for weak*-compact set of measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ be a measurable space and $\mathcal P$ a weak*-compact set of the set of all probability measures $\mathcal M_1(\Omega)$. Does there always exist a probability measure $\mathbb Q\in\mathcal M_1(\Omega)$ such that every $\mathbb P\in\mathcal P$ is absolutely continuous to $\mathbb Q$, i.e. such that $\mathbb Q$ dominates all measures in $\mathcal P$?

Comment: Can you precisely state what you mean by weak$^*$-compact?

Comment: the weak*-topology is usually taken to be the weakest topology such that the linear functionals $l_Z:\mathcal M_1(\Omega)\rightarrow\mathbb R$, defined by $l_Z(\mu)=\int_\mathbb R Zd\mu$ is continuous for every bounded and measurable function $Z:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is now answered at [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130470/existence-of-dominating-measure-for-weak-compact-set-of-measures).